# Chatter files zip or batch download?

Tags: chatter, chatter-file

I think the answer to this is no, and I cant find any documentation but is it possible to zip up or otherwise batch download a whole series of chatter files at once?

I have access to them all via soql but not sure the best way to batch them all together?

thinking of using something like this?

http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/

any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Yup no direct way to the best of my knowledge. Though there is a paid app to do it.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000055eZpEAI

How about writing an application to use REST or SOQL to download Chatter files?

Comment: hmm app looks interesting.  I'm all for writing an app to do it and i can write the SOQl just fine to grab them app but how would i combine them into a single download?